# What are the metro prices in Seoul

Tags: trains, public-transport, seoul

I am interested in the fares for the metro/bus system in downtown Seoul.

I have searched for a website or a proper table but I was not able to find anything. Do I need a travel card?

Can someone provide me a link or more information about this metro system. I am interested in a weekly or daily ticket with unlimited rides. Do they exist?

Moreover, do you know if the credit card is accepted as a method to buy metro tickets?

Comment: I found loads of information just by searching for "Seoul subway" and here is the one from the [Korea Tourism Organization](https://english.visitkorea.or.kr/enu/TRP/TP_ENG_6.jsp).

Comment: 1250 IIRC; at least around 1000 to 1300. Much like any Asian countries credit cards are unavailable for bus or metro.

Comment: @WeatherVane in the page you have linked there is no information about prices for weekly or daily ticket with unlimited rides. Do you have any experience with the Seoul subway?

Comment: @Blaszard 1250 is the base fare, it increases as you go over 10km or so, (very far), but only by about 10-30% of the base cost. A couple lines are considered luxury lines and charge the "extended" fare of 2400. i.e. the Shinbundang line (it's a metro that does red bus distances at the cost of a red bus ticket).

Comment: @insidesin Ah yes you are right. I had rarely used such long distances so forgot about it.

Comment: @Blaszard I'm agreeing with you, just improving with my knowledge. Seoul metro is my favourite thing in the world.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some reseach for you, and have found the following. As in the first reply to your question a page was linked, it listed some prices but not the prices you were looking for.

In South korean they have something like the T-Money Card, you can add funds on this card to travel with it.

But they also have something else called the MPASS,

> MPASS, is a transportation card exclusively for international tourists traveling in the Seoul metropolitan area and Jeju. The pass offers 20 rides a day for the duration of the pass. Additional funds can be loaded to MPASS and be used as a Tmoney card.

The prices for these cards vary on depending on the duration you want to have the card, it can be a 1-day card up till a 7-day card. The prices also vary a bit, I will mention them here, and also provide a link to the webpage where I found this.

Card Duration   Price   Discounted price (after 17:00)

- 1-day pass   15,000 won  12,000 won
- 2-day pass   23,000 won  20,000 won
- 3-day pass   30,500 won  27,500 won
- 5-day pass   47,500 won  44,500 won
- 7-day pass   64,500 won  61,500 won

The MPASS, can be used in the following areas:

- Seoul: subway lines, airport railroad all-stop train, mainline buses,
  branch buses, circulation buses, village buses, night buses
- Jeju: Jeju city buses ※ Jeju pass can be used both in Jeju and in the
  Seoul metropolitan area.

The ticket can also be bought at several locations like the airport, and in Seoul itself.
**Incheon International Airport**

- Tourist Information Center: Passenger Terminal 1, 1F, In front of Gates 5 & 10 / 07:00-22:00
- Airport Railroad Travel Center: Passenger Terminal 1, B1, In front of Airport Railroad All Stop Train Gate (purchase only) / 05:30-23:00
- **Refunds at the airport can only be made at the Tourist Information Center.**

**Seoul**

- Seoul Station Tmoney Town : 1F, Seoul City Tower near Seoul Station (Seoul Subway Line 1, 4, AREX), Exit 10 / 09:00-18:00
- [Myeong-dong Tourist Information Center](http://english.visitkorea.or.kr/enu/ATR/SI_EN_3_1_1_1.jsp?cid=1938975): In front of Euljiro 1(il)-ga Station (Seoul Subway Line 2), Exit 5 / 09:00-18:00

Source:
http://english.visitkorea.or.kr/enu/TRP/TP_ENG_8_1_2.jsp

Comment: Day passes for metro in Seoul is a waste of money. Unless you're going to travel about 10-15 times a day, which most people don't. The best thing for a tourist to get for travelling in Seoul is a T-money card and topping it up as you go. T-money is also national, so no "jeju and seoul only" bullshit.